# Using request within routes node / express

Tags: node.js, express, getjson

I'm playing around with using nodejs as a custom front end for drupal and i'm trying to come up with a way to match the backend menu system, blocks and views with the routing in express.

example route

```
module.exports = {
'/work': function(req, res){
    //get view json for this page
    request('http://site.api/casestudies', function(err, response, body){
        views_body = JSON.parse(body);

        //get node id from alias
        request('http://site.api/alias-to-nid' + req.url, function(err, response, body){
            body = JSON.parse(body);
            var reqUrl = 'http://site.api/rest/api/' + body.path;

            request(reqUrl, function(err, response, body){
                body = JSON.parse(body);
                //get the data we need
                var node_title = body.title,
                    node_body = body.body.und[0].safe_value,
                    pageclass = 'not-front section-work';
                res.render('work', {title: node_title, class:pageclass, node_title:node_title, node_body:node_body, views_body:views_body});
            });
        });
    });
  }
}
```

So, i hit /work and grab the json for the casestudies view that should exist on that page, then i lookup the node id from the /work alias using another request and finally use the node id in yet another nested request call to grab the rest of the json for the page before finally sending it on the the template.

Now - I have a feeling that this is a terrible way to go about this. What should I be doing instead!?

Comment: You need https://github.com/caolan/async, particularly `parallel` and `waterfall`.

Comment: thanks @TrevorDixon have been playing with this, looks like it'll do the job!